# Does an OS kernel communicate with a process in the same ways as IPC?

Tags: linux, windows, process, operating-system, ipc

A process communicate with another process using [various ways of IPC (interprocess communication)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication#Approaches), such as shared memory, message passing, signaling?

I learn that [an OS kernel can communicate with a process using signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279464/are-signals-generated-by-os-kernels-or-processes), and if I am right, signaling by the same signals is also a way of IPC.

Does an OS kernel communicate with a process or processes using other ways of IPC, such as shared memory, message passing?

If needs to be specific, I would like to know about Linux kernel the most, and also am happy to know about Windows kernel.

Comment: linux is monolithic as an architecture, meaning whole kernel is  one big module and kernel inter-/intra- communication is done via signals (like unix systems). Other kernels are modular or *micro-kernels* and these use more flexible (and slower) IPC

Comment: Do some Googling please!  In about 30 seconds I was reading  the source code to signal.c which implements the signal sending mechanism.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad.  There are many many ways in which an OS can "communicate" with user-mode code.  Arguably, every single API call the user-mode code makes is a form of communication.

Comment: @Harry:  "every single API call the user-mode code makes" is a way that a process communicate to an OS kernel, not a way that an OS kernel communicate to a process.

Comment: It's the same thing; if I'm communicating with you, you're communicating with me. If you mean unsolicited communication, I'm not sure that either the Windows or Linux kernels ever do that. SIGPIPE isn't really unsolicited, e.g., because it is a direct response to a specific situation arising during an API call; the fact that it is a signal rather than an error code is just an implementation detail. (So if SIGPIPE counts as "communicating" then so does returning an error code.)  Perhaps you could narrow down your definitions, or provide context?  As-is, I don't really know what you're asking.

Comment: @Harry: I mean unidirectional communication from an OS kernel to a process, not bidirectional one, unless I am wrong.

Comment: I don't think there's really any useful way to categorize kernel/process interactions as uni- or bi-directional.  But perhaps someone else will understand what you're getting at.  At any rate, the most direct answer to your original question I can give is to mention that I have seen questions about third-party Windows device drivers (which run as part of the kernel) that communicate with user-mode via shared memory and (less often) named pipes.

Answer (score 2):

The question suggests a fundamental misunderstanding of the structure of most operating systems.

There is no separate "kernel" process to communicate with. The kernel is code that runs in the context of any process. Kernel kernel code is invoked by an interrupt, trap, or exception. While in kernel mode the process has access to the kernel memory that is shared by all processes.

Therefore, there cannot be interprocess communication between a process and the kernel.

When a kernel sends a signal (in Unix) or APC (in Windoze) it does so within the context of the process that is receiving the signal.

Some signals can be created outside the receiving process. The general sequence is:

Process P enters kernel mode and queues a signal within kernel memory to process Q.
When Process Q becomes the current process, the kernel arranges for Q to execute a signal handler.

For such a signal, the communication is between P and Q; not Q and the kernel.

Keep in mind that that signal mechanism originated back in the days when Unix only had single streams of execution. It was a poor-man's form of asychronous procedure call (as on Windoze or VMS). There was a time when any form of parallel processing on eunuchs required creating a separate process. The [poorly designed] signal model does not differentiate between externally generated/asynchronous/synchronous events.

Windoze (NT) followed the VMS model of using software interrupts to notify the process of events. This interrupt model is largely hidden behind the Windows API that converts the interrupt model into an event model.

In the interrupt model, a process could queue multiple I/O request to (e.g.) 100 separate network connections, terminal, or disk drives. As part of the operating system service, the caller can specify a procedure to be called when the request completes. Let's assume it's 100 terminals.

A single process (application) can manage any number of devices in this type of system.

A process could get notification if any one of the terminals disconnected through a software interrupt. The parameters to the interrupt handler would identify the specific device so that the hander could reestablish the connection or clean up.

In classic Unix (before threads) you would have to create a separate process for each terminal. The process would sit and wait on a "read" or "write: operation waiting for the terminal to respond. The process would get a SIGHUP signal if the terminal disconnected.

In Windoze, signals are part of the C library, translating software interrupts into something that looks like a unix signal.

Comment: Thanks. I know kernel isn't process. That's why I am asking if an OS kernel communicates to a process using the same ways as IPC.